# where to set nullpointerexception

Tags: java, eclipse

im very new in developing an android app.. when i run my program in the emulator it force close.. i figure it out that i need to set an nullpointerexception but i dont know where to set those stuff.. pls help me.

public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

```
TextView dp_octet1, dp_octet2, dp_octet3, dp_octet4, dp_slashes;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int octet[];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
    iniTextView();
    generatingRandomIpAddress();
}

private void generatingRandomIpAddress() {


   Random i = new Random();           //Random number between 0-2
   if(i.nextInt(3)==0){
       octet[0] = 8+(i.nextInt(22));
       octet[1] = 1+(i.nextInt(126));
   }
   if(i.nextInt(3)==1){
       octet[0] = 16+(i.nextInt(14));
       octet[1] = 128+(i.nextInt(63));
   }
   if(i.nextInt(3)==2){
       octet[0] = 24+(i.nextInt(6));
       octet[1] = 192+(i.nextInt(31));
   }
   octet[2] = (i.nextInt(255));
   octet[3] = (i.nextInt(255));
   octet[4] = (i.nextInt(255));

   //Display the problem
   dp_slashes.setText(octet[0]);
   dp_octet1.setText(octet[1]);
   dp_octet2.setText(octet[2]);
   dp_octet3.setText(octet[3]);
   dp_octet4.setText(octet[4]);

}



private void iniTextView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dp_octet1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.octet1);
    dp_octet2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.octet2);
    dp_octet3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.octet3);
    dp_octet4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.octet4);
    dp_slashes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.slashes);
}
```

log cat

08-05 09:11:07.180: D/AndroidRuntime(1286): Shutting down VM
08-05 09:11:07.180: W/dalvikvm(1286): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myscratches/com.example.myscratches.SampleActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at com.example.myscratches.SampleActivity.generatingRandomIpAddress(SampleActivity.java:32)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at com.example.myscratches.SampleActivity.onCreate(SampleActivity.java:24)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-05 09:11:07.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `octet` before you can start assigning values to its elements. Change your declaration to:

```
int octet[] = new int[4];
```

Alternatively, add this line:

```
octet = new int[4];
```

to `generatingRandomIpAddress()` before you start assigning to the elements of `octet`.

P.S. In the future, when you are asking for help with an exception, you should post the logcat output showing the stack trace for the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this applies to ADT, but if I had a piece of Java code in which a NullPointerException was being thrown and I had to find out where it was being thrown, I would do one of the following :

1. Go through the stack trace
2. Put an Exception Breakpoint.

For the #2 above, take a look at [**this**](http://bit.ly/McPEbp). If you choose 'Uncaught' while setting up this breakpoint, the execution should automatically halt when *any* NullPointer exception is thrown.